# can an event listener be extracted as method in java while refactoring?

Tags: refactoring, event-listener

This is an event listener.  I want to extract it as a method.  Would it have any effect on the execution of the program or on the invocation of the event?

```
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            isKill = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                isKill = false;
            }
        });

Comment: No.  Extracting as a method would have no significant impact.